# WPF canvas and placing items

Tags: wpf, canvas

I want an image as background that would uniform stretch. Then i want my canvas to have size equal to uniform stretched image.(A workaround i found is to have inside a grid the image and canvas and bind canvas width/height to image actual height/width).

Then i want to have items inside the canvas that will be absolutely positioned.But here is the problem.If an item X is 50 and image is 200px width then its ok. But if image gets 100px width item X should be 25.Also i want a small scale transform. Is there a way to achieve this via binding ?
Do i have to implement my custom panel usercontrol because i see no other clean solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could certainly achieve all this by binding, but i guess that it would be a lot easier and cleaner to create a derived Panel that arranges children at positions relative to the Panel's ActualWidth and Actualheight.

The derived Panel class could define attached properties for child positions, similar to Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top, but with fractional values ranging from 0 to 1.

It could also maintain the background image as dependency property. You would override the [OnRender](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.onrender.aspx) method to directly draw this image.

The Panel could also calculate a current scale factor from dividing e.g. its ActualWidth by the image's width. An appropriate [ScaleTransform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.scaletransform.aspx) property would be easily attached to each child's RenderTransform.

EDIT: Except the uniformity of the Panel's dimension relative to the background image, the following might give you an idea of how that panel could be implemented:

```
public class ImagePanel : Panel
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LeftProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Left", typeof(double), typeof(ImagePanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PositionChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TopProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Top", typeof(double), typeof(ImagePanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(PositionChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(ImagePanel),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

    private ScaleTransform scaleTransform = new ScaleTransform();

    public static double GetLeft(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(LeftProperty);
    }

    public static void SetLeft(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(LeftProperty, value);
    }

    public static double GetTop(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(TopProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTop(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TopProperty, value);
    }

    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        if (Image != null)
        {
            dc.DrawImage(Image, new Rect(0d, 0d, ActualWidth, ActualHeight));
        }

        base.OnRender(dc);
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);

        if (Image != null)
        {
            scaleTransform.ScaleX = sizeInfo.NewSize.Width / Image.Width;
            scaleTransform.ScaleY = sizeInfo.NewSize.Height / Image.Height;
        }
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
        {
            element.Measure(availableSize);
        }

        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        foreach (UIElement element in InternalChildren)
        {
            element.RenderTransform = scaleTransform;
            ArrangeElement(element, finalSize.Width, finalSize.Height);
        }

        return finalSize;
    }

    private static void PositionChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as UIElement;
        var panel = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(obj) as ImagePanel;

        if (element != null && panel != null)
        {
            ArrangeElement(element, panel.ActualWidth, panel.ActualHeight);
        }
    }

    private static void ArrangeElement(UIElement element, double width, double height)
    {
        var left = GetLeft(element);
        var top = GetLeft(element);
        var rect = new Rect(new Point(left * width, top * height), element.DesiredSize);

        element.Arrange(rect);
    }
}
```

Comment: currenlty i do use binding somehow but it messes the model for no reason. This seems promising. I dont know how to define attached properties but i guess i could figure out. The 0..1 seems great idea as i can let the user position the elements where he wants without having to display the image at full size at start or whatever. Is there a way to cache the image ?Because i want about 4-5 panels otherwise.Also if i put scaletransform at each child how would it take its factor? I mean binding or by code from panel? If binding that means an extra property at my POCO ? Thank you

Comment: "Is there a way to cache the image": WPF should cache bitmaps in memory, otherwise System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache would be an option. "ScaleTransform by binding or by code from panel": Easiest approach would be to simply set each child's RenderTransform property (e.g. in Panel.ArrangeOverride), but of course the children then can't define their own RenderTransform. Binding to something like `Parent.ScaleTransform` should also be possible, without any extra viewmodel property.

Comment: Thank you!ok seems that it works. The problem now is that using attached property for position how can i allow user to move it ?I use a thumb but i should somehow map dX movement into 0..1 somehow

Comment: If you need to move items, i guess you it would be better to use absolute coordinates like Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top.